# How to use guest user Wish-list to database in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter-3

Guest user has added wish-list to a particular product in the product list. How to visible a wish-list to list of products?.

How to maintain guest user data in the database?.

Answer (score 0):

You can use session_d from the browsers. This is the only thread between guest user and server. You can map it back to the user if he logs in.